# Java try-with-resource on SQL statement will these close properly?

Tags: java, sql

I had a very sophisticated class that performed DB queries, the problem is it wasnt using try-with-resource statements so i had to .close() manually. To be safer, I tried to re-design it with try-with-resource. My question is if these resources will close properly given how I'm referencing them outside the objects containing those resources. For example, this class DBQuery i use to create queries and resources related to those queries

```
public class DBQuery {

private String _query;
private PreparedStatement _stmt;
private ResultSet _rs;


// constructor
public DBQuery (String query) {
    _query = query;
}

public PreparedStatement execPreparedStatement() throws SQLException {
    _stmt = DB.getCon().prepareStatement(_query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    return _stmt;
}

public ResultSet getRecordSet() throws SQLException {
    _rs = _stmt.executeQuery();
    return _rs;
}
    
public void setInt(int paramNum, int setVal) throws SQLException {
    _stmt.setInt(paramNum, setVal);
}

public void setString(int paramNum, String setVal) throws SQLException {
    _stmt.setString(paramNum, setVal);
}

}
```

Then this would be example usage of the class. loadActiveCompany given a companyId retrieves the company from the database and creates some objects. My question is two-fold:

1. will the resources close properly when loadActiveCompany completes.
2. is there any problem with how I'm using the try-catch blocks.

Thank you

```
// loads the active company into the view
public void loadActiveCompany(int companyId) {
    
    boolean loadFailed = false;

    // we are passed the company id
    _activeCompany.setCompanyId(companyId);
    
    DBQuery qComps = new DBQuery("SELECT comp_name FROM comps WHERE id=?");
    try ( PreparedStatement stmtComps = qComps.execPreparedStatement() ) {
        
        DB.getCon().rollback();
        
        qComps.setInt(1, companyId);
        try ( ResultSet rsComps = qComps.getRecordSet() ) {
            rsComps.next();
            String companyName = rsComps.getString("comp_name");
            _activeCompany.setCompanyName(companyName);
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find company!");
        loadFailed = true;

    } finally {
        if (loadFailed) 
            return;
    }       

    DBQuery qGroups = new DBQuery("SELECT id, group_name FROM comps_groups WHERE comp_id=? ORDER BY sort_order ASC");
    try ( PreparedStatement stmtGroups = qGroups.execPreparedStatement() ) {
        
        qGroups.setInt(1, companyId);
        try ( ResultSet rsGroups = qGroups.getRecordSet() ) {
            
            while (rsGroups.next()) {
            
                int groupId = rsGroups.getInt("id");
                Group thisGroup = new Group();
                thisGroup.setGroupId(groupId);
                thisGroup.setGroupName(rsGroups.getString("group_name"));
                DBQuery qAnchors = new DBQuery("SELECT id, anchor_name, anchor_type FROM comps_groups_anchors WHERE group_id=? ORDER BY sort_order ASC");
                
                try ( PreparedStatement stmtAnchors = qAnchors.execPreparedStatement() ) {
                                
                    qAnchors.setInt(1, groupId);
                    try ( ResultSet rsAnchors = qAnchors.getRecordSet() ) {
                                    
                        while (rsAnchors.next()) {
                            int anchorId = rsAnchors.getInt("id");
                            Anchor thisAnchor = new Anchor();
                            thisAnchor.setAnchorId(anchorId);
                            thisAnchor.setAnchorName(qAnchors.getRS().getString("anchor_name"));
                            thisAnchor.setAnchorType(qAnchors.getRS().getInt("anchor_type"));
                            thisGroup.addGroupAnchor(thisAnchor);
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
                _activeCompany.getCompanyGroups().add(thisGroup);
            }
        }
        
        DB.getCon().commit();
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load company!");
        loadFailed = true;
        
    } finally {
        if (loadFailed)
            return;
    }
    
    // print out the active company
    _activeCompany.printStatus();
}
```

Comment: You are placing both PreparedStatements in try-with-resources statements, so there is no problem here at all.  (As a bonus, closing a Statement [automatically closes its associated ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#close()).)

Comment: Awesome good to know thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

1. Yes, the `PreparedStatement`s are all closed.
2. Not directly problems, but easier ways.

Here my BUTs:

- The name `execPreparedStatement` is totally misleading, as it is not (in DB terms) executing anything, just creating the `PreparedStatement`. A better name would be `createPreparedStatement` or - lol - `preparePreparedStatement`
- Why do you call `DB.getCon().rollback();`? I do not think this will lead to someplace good...
- the way you use `DBQuery` at the moment, it will only bring pain. Basicall this is just a container that saves additional infos (`_stmt` + `_rs`) which makes it SEVERELY state and sequence dependent, prone to hit you with lots of NPEs
- - so the actions you call on `DBQuery` you could simply also call on the `PreparedStatement`, reducing complexity and taking away a few pitfalls
- - so either completely remove `DBQuery`
- - or remodel the `DBQuery`
- - - to be `Closeable`/`AutoCloseable`,
- - - add some checks to the other functions,
- - - create the `PreparedStatement` right away (CTOR, query string as CTOR parameter),
- - - keep it private, do not expose it
- - - use it inside `getRecordSet`,
- - - do not store any other references unless you REALLY need them
- - - and in the `close` method close the PS,
- Your `loadFailed = true;` and `if (loadFailed) return;` seems overly convoluted and error-prone. Why not directly call `return;` right where you currently have `loadFailed = true;` lines?
- I would - personal preference - put those 2 whole try-catch blocks into their own methods, signaling failure with a boolean or something => more methods with each less code and better variable scope (for example no re-use of `loadFailed`, but better re-usability of the two methods)
- You actually do NOT need the inner try-resource on the `ResultSet`s, but it's good if you (can) keep em. Just be careful there, as closing a `ResultSet` might have an impact on its creator `PreparedStatement`. So if you test it (in a situation where you re-use the `PreparedStatement`, that what it's actually made for) and get a 'closed' Exception when reusing the `PreparedStatement`, then you remove the try-resource blocks around the `ResultSet`s.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer! I appreciate it. I totally agree the DBQuery class i posted is kind of useless, but it was a simplified version of the actual class which is more useful and has many more methods. A lot of your tips still apply.  About the rollback(), I thought it might be cleaner to just call rollback() at the start of any SQL try block, then commit when I'm done. That would save me having to wrap rollback in another try/catch block at the end of each method? Kind of out-of-the-box but is there a good reason not to do it that way?

Comment: Kind of rollback first if there's anything to rollback, if last sql committed there will be nothing to roll back, but if last sql failed then rollback first when we try more sql

Comment: `DB.getCon().rollback();` looks like a static access, which would mean that you cannot exclude the situation that two or more Threads are working on that connection. Simply rolling it back for no obvious reasons might severely interfere with the tasks of other Threads. If you still wanna deal with those details, you can either wrap them up in `DBQuery` (save fail when requesting, then in the `close` method rollback) or use and handle **transactions** manually. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html for examples.